# How do you extract reddit submission content with praw?

Tags: discord.py, praw

I'm working on a Discord bot right now, where one of its commands brings up a random submission from the r/copypasta subreddit. Right now, my code is as follows:

```
@client.command(help = 'sends you a link to a copypasta... working on making it an embed')
async def copypasta(ctx):
    reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = 'XXXX', 
                         client_secret = 'XXXX', 
                         username = 'XXXX', 
                         password = 'XXXX', 
                         user_agent = 'XXXX')
    submission = reddit.subreddit("copypasta").random()
    e = discord.Embed(title=f'{submission.title}', description=f'{submission.url} \n \n requested by {ctx.author.mention}', color=0xFFFFF)

    await ctx.send(embed = e)
```

I'm looking to change the description to the actual content of the submission: that is, **instead of sending the URL, it would actually send the copypasta.** I've looked through the documentation, and I've found no method of doing so. How would I extract the submission and place it in my embed?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `selftext` property of `Submission`. It'll be empty if the link is just a post.

Your code should look like this:

```
e = discord.Embed(title=f'{submission.title}', description=f'{submission.selftext} \n \n requested by {ctx.author.mention}', color=0xFFFFF)
```

Documentation Link: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html?highlight=submission